# three.js camera matrix position

Tags: three.js, webgl

when one writes

```
camera.position.z=100
```

which matrix gets updated?

because i do not see any changes in

```
camera.matrix, camera.matrixWorld, or camera.matrixWorldInverse
```

Also, this updates the camera's position locally correct? If so how can you updated it globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these matrices get updated. But only at render time.